# How are you monitoring in version 0.11 of Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I registered the issue with Github, but I could not get the answer I wanted, so I asked here.
( https://github.com/Morningstar/kafka-offset-monitor/issues/12  )

If you are running Kafka in version 0.11, I am wondering how you are monitoring.

I want to monitor the system part, but the general parts like "producer", "consumer", "lag" etc. KafkaOffsetMonitor (https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor) Consumers "error.

If you have any problems facing me, please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at  https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to monitor. It's easy to setup and free.